# Access Android device from my Android phone, via USB

Tags: android, file, usb

We have a coffee machine at work (a Coffee Queen CQUBE Evo). It has a touch screen interface and a USB connection.

I see, in the maintenance manual, that the supplier's technicians use this USB connection with a pre-programmed USB stick.

I also see, again in the manual, that the interface in the coffee machine is built on Android. They call their app Luna (if it matters to anyone reading this).

When I connect my Android phone to the coffee machine, via the before mentioned USB connection, I get the choice between charging or transferring photos / files from the phone to the device (the coffee machine).

My question is whether I, via this connection, can access the file system on the coffee machine?

I want this access to e.g. change photos that are there, in terms of internal branding, change wallpapers according to season, etc.

Best regards

Comment: You would need to ask the manufacturer.

Comment: Thank you for your thougts :) I'm still waiting for an answer from the dealer. In the meantime I'm checking other possibilities, considering this is an Android device, thinking there might be a way to access the file system directly, through the USB connection :)

Comment: Sure, but unless somebody else happens to have run this very experiment on this very make/model of coffee maker, we're not going to be able to answer the question.

Comment: Hi, This doesn't seem like a Stackoverflow kind-of-a question.  Stackoverflow is mainly for programming questions.  You might want to post this question at similar sites, such as stackexchange.com or quora.com.  Maybe even at a site  dealing with hacking/security, because the coffee machine was probably designed to not allow access/manipulation of its files directly.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for all input :) I'll take all advice into condiseration in my quest for a solution :) Happy hollidays!